# How do I fix this regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
String input = "2012 AL REG TEXT 300535(NS)";
String regex = "^((\\d{4})\\s+)?((\\S+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+)\\s+((\\S+)(\\s+\\(.*?\\)))$";
```

I want to capture 2012 in a group, "AL REG TEXT" in another group, and "300535(NS)" in another group.

Comment: Too little info: what are the patterns you are trying to capture, how much can they deviate. What are the issues you are facing?

Comment: It is always going to be in the input format as above. I'm trying to capture a group of 4 numbers which is the year, then a name of the form "AL REG TEXT" and another number like "300535(NS)"

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't capture any group.

Comment: You can use (?<name>  regex     ) for named groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you have an extra `\\s+` right before the expected parantheses and, as @cmonkey points out, an extra `\\s+` in the middle. Remove these and it works. Also, to only get the groups you mention above, add `?:` to the ones you don't want to capture:

```
String input = "2012 AL REG TEXT 300535(NS)";
String regex = "^(?:(\\d{4})\\s+)?((?:\\S+)\\s+(?:.+?))\\s+((?:\\S+)(?:\\(.*?\\)))$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.format("Group %d: '%s'%n", i, m.group(i));
    }
}
```

prints

```
Group 1: '2012'
Group 2: 'AL REG TEXT'
Group 3: '300535(NS)'
```

Comment: i'm only interested in getting group1, group3, group6 .. can I make this expression compact ?

Comment: @Phoenix: Edited to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of your regex, there is the portion:

```
\\s+)\\s+
```

Which is looking for two required consecutive spaces. This does not exist, so the regex fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^(\\d{4})?\\s+(\\D+)\\s+(\\d.*)$`

Here's the code:

```
    String input = "2012 AL REG TEXT 300535(NS)";
    String regex = "^(\\d{4})?\\s+(\\D+)\\s+(\\d.*)$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Group count: "+m.groupCount());
        for(int i=0; i<=m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Group "+i+": "+m.group(i));
        }
    }
    else System.out.println("No match");
```